# Only the first marker showing on google map

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have a problem showing addresses on Google Maps. I have tried everything but its not working. It shows only the first marker even if I click on other addresses.  How can I get it to show the other markers?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Attractions/Museums">
<a href="#maps" data-role="button" id="addMarker" onclick="addMarker();" data-theme="c">     <xsl:value-of select="address"/></a>
</xsl:for-each>
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
$( "#maps" ).on( 'pageshow', function() {
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
})

// initialize the map 
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);    
function addMarker() {
var address = document.getElementById("addMarker").text;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var image = 'flag1.png';
   var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your links (anchor tags) have the same ID attribute, so when the function runs it pick the last one to take the marker data from.

Try using different ID attribute for each link and sending the function that ID as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 
I have noticed that but because the data is been read from XML file using xsl, it's tricky. It loops around to read the data therefore I'm looking for an alternative way around it!!

Comment: It shouldn't be tricky, you just need to change the ID of each link. I assume each address has a different ID in the database, why not use that?

Comment: No, the data tags are similar inside the XML document that's why I use the xsl to loop around and fetch the data. I have tried to get the element by tagName, name and other different ways but it didn't work. Tried markers Array and it didn't work, I'm new to google Maps

Comment: Than maybe just try to have an index variable that counts the nodes inside the for each loop and use that as an ID

Comment: You should also be able to use the 'this' keyword to access the element that initiated the event and get its days from there.

Comment: A lot of information about the this keyword can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: If you think I gave you the accepted answer, I would appreciate if you accept it.