# Only first InfoWindow showing on Google Map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Why is it that only the first (one only) InfoWindow showing on Google Map? I want all of the pinned address show InfoWindow.

I already searched for answers like [Only the first marker showing on google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645407/only-the-first-marker-showing-on-google-map) , [Google Maps API InfoWindow only showing the first location for all the markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682597/google-maps-api-infowindow-only-showing-the-first-location-for-all-the-markers) and [Google maps-api v3 InfoWindow automatically open on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342994/google-maps-api-v3-infowindow-automatically-open-on-page-load) but still no luck.

here is my code.

```
  $scope.initialise = function(){

    $http.get('http://remoteapi.com/' + $scope.name)
        .success(function(data) 
        {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(8.4844173, 124.6526134);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            for( var i in data ) {
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lon);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    content: data[i].description
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: "<img style='max-width:50px;max-height50px;' src='images/"+data[i].image+"'>"
                  });

            }

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
              });
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

  };

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map"), 'load', $scope.initialise());
```

Comment: Create only 1 infowindow (outside of your for loop). Then use `.setContent()` method in your marker click event listener.

Comment: Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rmp7gjth/

Comment: sorry, I cannot understand. Do you mind to provide snippet of it?

Comment: I didn't mind. It's just above your last comment... ;-)